# Different problems with my font

Tags: css, fonts

I'm looking for help regarding some font issues i have. I'm working on my new online store and we're using a Swedish e-commerce platform. We have access to the CSS code, but not HTML.

I'm using the "Questrial" font, which looks great in Chrome and Safari (i have a Mac). However, on Firefox it doesn't look as good. I'm using "all-small-caps" for the headlines and links in the menu and these become too thick in Firefox.

This also brings me to my next question. I logged in and checked how it would look at my phone (Galaxy S6) and to my surprise, none of the headlines nor links were in small caps - just regular letters. It's obvious that the phones browser don't like the "all-small-caps".

My question is if there is anything i can do to fix these two problems? Down below you find the relevant CSS code i'm using at the moment.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

```
<pre>
a {
    color: grey;
    font-weight: normal;
}

li a {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-variant: all-small-caps;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        font-weight: normal;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-variant: all-small-caps;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.tws-articles-two {
    font-variant: all-small-caps;
    font-weight: normal;
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The font-variant property doesn't seem compatible in the mobile. You can check the details in this [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant)

Also it has compatibility for older version for desktop based browsers.

> Update:

You can use text-transform property to change the text format.

Comment: You have any other solution i could try?

Comment: you mean "font-variant: smallcaps" and "text-transform: lowercase"?

Comment: yeah you can do that

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot Abhay! Do you know anyhow i can work around my other problem? With the small-caps being too thick in Firefox.

Comment: For thickness you can use the font-weight property. It will work.